# replace null value with random value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

i have data where there are missing values in salary1 column and i am trying to replace it with a range between the minimum value and maximum value. i tried with below code but got error. could someone please help me? thank in advance.

code

```
a = df['salary1'].max()
b = df['salary1'].min()
df['salary1'] = df['salary1'].replace(np.nan, range(b,a))
```

error

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

data

```
salary1 Experience
0   NaN 2
1   100000.0    3
2   NaN 4
3   NaN 4
4   NaN 1
... ... ...
12884   NaN 1
12885   NaN 3
12886   150000.0    2
12887   NaN 2
12888   NaN 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges) is the wrong function to use. `list(range(a,b))` returns a sequence of numbers from `a` to (but not including) `b`. For example, `list(range(5,10))` returns `[5,6,7,8,9]`

Try with [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['salary1'] = df['salary1'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.notnull(x) else np.random.randint(df['salary1'].min(), df['salary1'].max()))
```

###### Example:

```
>>> df
    salary1
0  100000.0
1       NaN
2  150000.0
3       NaN
4  175000.0
5       NaN

>>> df['salary1'].apply(lambda x: x if pd.notnull(x) else np.random.randint(df['salary1'].min(), df['salary1'].max()))
0    100000.0
1    119091.0
2    150000.0
3    171438.0
4    175000.0
5    114396.0
Name: salary1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

`range` returns a sequence/iterator, use [np.random.rand](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the below code you are generating random int between range [a,b]-

```
df['salary1'] = df['salary1'].replace(np.nan, random.randint(a, b))
```

Comment: This will replace every `NaN` with the same "random" integer. I think OP wants to generate a new random number for each `NaN`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I feel the best practice would be to replace it with average.

Comment: Not really, if OP needs a new random number for each, it's definitely doable with `apply`. (see my answer if you want to know how)